# If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0$.

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $f,f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0.$$

First of all, is $f'$ defined a.e. ? Because there are no assumption on the fact that $f$ is derivable. So, is $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
for almost every $x$ ?

My attempt for the statement : Suppose WLOG $f'>0$. I'm not sure if it's true, but I would say that : Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $f'$ is $L^1$, there is a ball $[a,b]$ s.t. $$\int_{]-\infty ,a[\cup]b,+\infty [}f'(x)dx<\varepsilon .$$
In particular, if $x>y>b$, then $$f(x)-f(y)=\int_y^x f'(t)dt<\varepsilon,$$
but I just can conclude that $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)-f(y)<\varepsilon .$

Comment: For the first question, why not?  It's written "$f' \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$" in the title.  If $f'$ is not defined a.e., this condition would be meaningless.  It suffices to show the case for $f\ge0$.  Try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: Thanks but how do you think $f'$ is defined ? In the weak sense or as I defined in my post ?

Comment: @user659895 Do you know that there exist continuous strictly increasing functions $f$ with $f'=0$ almost everywhere. Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC) is proved under the assumption that $f$ has a  continuous derivative and you cannot make such assumptions in this question. So use of FTC is not at all admissible here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not properly posed. Normally the statement is interpreted as follows: if $f$ is integrable and differentiable almost everywhere with $f'$ also integrable then $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$. This statement is false. $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is an integer and $0$ otherwise gives a counterexample. Some additional assumptions on $f$ are necessary to prove that $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$.

Comment: but $f=1$ is not integrable...

Comment: $f=1$ only at integer points which form a set of measure $0$. @user659895

Comment: Strange because to prove that the fourier transform of the derivative is $\mathcal F(f')(\alpha )=-2i\pi \alpha \mathcal F(f)(\alpha )$, in my exercise the only assumption are $f,f'\in L^1$

Comment: In such results it is generally assumed that $f$ is an **absolutely continuous** function such that $f$ and $f'$ are integrable.

Comment: It appears that the downvoter  doesn't care about Mathematical rigor.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the hypothesis state that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, you can see it when $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is written. It is because $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is assumed when we write $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Please, review that:
$$
L^p(X) = \left\{g : X \to \mathbb{R}, {\left(\int_X {|g|}^p\right)}^{\frac{1}{p}} < \infty\right\}\mbox{.}
$$

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to show that $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'$ hence $f$ has a limit in $\infty$, which must be $0$ because $f\in L^1$.

Answer (score -1):

On the one hand, observe that exists $l = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. It is because for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) - f(a) = \int_{(a , x)} f' \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = f(a) + \int_{(a , \infty)} f' \in \mathbb{R}\mbox{,}
$$
as $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. On the other hand, if $l \neq 0$, then there exist $\varepsilon , x_0 \in (0 , \infty)$ such that $|f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \geq x_0$. Therefore
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \geq \int_{[x_0 , \infty)} |f| \geq \varepsilon \int_{[x_0 , \infty)} 1 = \infty\mbox{,}
$$
which is a contradiction, as $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You are making some strong assumptions. The hypothesis does not guarantee that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is applicable.

Comment: Hypothesis guarantee that the FTC is applicable because $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, you can remember the FTC's hypothesis here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: It is not given that $f$ is continuous and it is not given that $f$ is differentiabel at every point. The statement, as it stands, is false as I have pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I think that you are wrong: if $f \in L^1(X)$, normally we suppose that $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In analysis we often talk of $f'$ even when $f$ need not be everywhere-differentiable, only requiring that $f$ be differentiable almost-everywhere instead. Under this interpretation, FToC need not hold. Even if $f$ is everywhere differentiable and $f'$ is integrable, it is a quite non-trivial result that FToC holds for this case, which is often skipped in many analysis textbook. (Rudin's RCA is a notable exception, and he proves this fact using [Vitali–Carathéodory theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem).)

Comment: @SangchulLee I do not want to take away your reason, but what do you thing at first when you read: "Let $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function"? At least I think that it is differentiable on $X$, and for me it is the same that if I read $g'$.

If I find $f'$ in a text, I have always supposed that $f$ is differentiable (everywhere). If one wants to mean that it's differentiable almost-everywhere, one should to write it explicitly.

Comment: @joseabp91, I understand your point. Perhaps it is so common in measure theory to consider a.e.-differentiable functions that people (including myself) are not sure as to whether OP is interested in everywhere-differentiability or a.e.-differentiability. I personally think it is OP's duty to clear the doubts.

Comment: @SangchulLee sorry but if I read $f'$ I think that everypeople must guess that it is differentiable (everywhere), even in measure theory, unless we read something like "differentiable almost-everywhere".